# Delete/Hide similar records having 'Pass' results

Tags: php, mysql

Hello I'm stuck with this problem for quite a few days. I'm not sure which codes
I can use (select if or maybe use 2 different query?)

This is how my current code displays my table

```
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| id    |  class  |  direction  |  test  |  results | Primary Key |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
| 22    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Fail    |  45678963   |
| 22    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |  45998963   |
| 22    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Fail    |  98578963   |
| 22    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |  13578763   |    
| 22    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |  35553624   |
| 22    |    A    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |  54889541   |
| 22    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |  87895412   |
| 22    |    B    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |  88845644   |
| 22    |    B    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |  96232142   |
| 22    |    B    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |  11123447   |
| 33    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |  12134597   |
| 33    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |  23654668   |
| 33    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Fail    |  78454675   |
| 33    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |  98754651   |
| 33    |    A    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |  69865232   |
| 33    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Fail    |  22235652   |
| 33    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |  85454555   |
| 33    |    B    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |  98665423   |
| 33    |    B    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |  22115645   |
| 33    |    B    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |  56654789   |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------+
```

but this is the table I need

```
               +---------------------------------------------------+
               | id    |  class  |  direction  |  test  |  results |
               +---------------------------------------------------+
               | 22    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Fail    |
##Delete/Hide##| 22    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |##Delete/Hide##
               | 22    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Fail    |
##Delete/Hide##| 22    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |##Delete/Hide##    
               | 22    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 22    |    A    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 22    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |
               | 22    |    B    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |
               | 22    |    B    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 22    |    B    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 33    |    A    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |
               | 33    |    A    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    | 
               | 33    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Fail    |
##Delete/Hide##| 33    |    A    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |##Delete/Hide##
               | 33    |    A    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 33    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Fail    |
##Delete/Hide##| 33    |    B    |   left      |  abc   |  Pass    |##Delete/Hide##
               | 33    |    B    |   right     |  abc   |  Pass    |
               | 33    |    B    |   left      |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               | 33    |    B    |   right     |  xyz   |  Pass    |
               +---------------------------------------------------+
```

I want to remove the rows with "Pass" whenever there's a similar id, 
class, direction, test and the result has a fail.

I'm not really sure how to code this properly. Any help would be appreciated. 
Thank you.

This is the code I use to take data from the database

```
$query= "SELECT DISTINCT `id`, class, `direction`,`test`, `results` FROM `table`";
   $result=mysqli_query($connect, $query);

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo $row[0];
        echo $row[1];
        echo $row[2];
        echo $row[3];
        echo $row[4];
   }
```

Comment: is any primary key to this table ?

Comment: Please show the table create code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the `DELETE` query:

```
DELETE YT 
FROM your_table YT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    id,
    class,
    direction,
    test
    FROM your_table
    WHERE results ='Fail'
    GROUP BY id,class,direction,test
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
) AS t 
ON YT.id = t.id AND YT.class = t.class AND YT.direction = t.direction AND YT.test = t.test 
WHERE YT.results = 'Pass'
```

**Explanation:**

The inner query will return only those rows which have `fail` status at least once.

Then making an `inner join` between your main table and the result returned by the inner query will generate result consisting of those records which have `fail` and `pass` statuses.

Later filtering these records based on only `Pass` statuses will leave only those records that you want to delete.

**EDIT:**

In order to hide such records instead of deleting you need to introduce a column say `is_deleted` which will hold `0/1` value.

`is_deleted = 0 means not deleted`

`is_deleted = 1 means deleted`.

**Steps:**

**First**: you need to add the column `is_deleted` to your table.

```
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD is_deleted TINYINT DEFAULT 0;
```

**Second**: You need an update query to update the status of `is_deleted` field of  such entries to `1`.

```
UPDATE 
your_table YT
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT 
    id,
    class,
    direction,
    test
    FROM your_table
    WHERE results ='Fail'
    GROUP BY id,class,direction,test
    HAVING COUNT(*) >= 1
) AS t 
ON YT.id = t.id AND YT.class = t.class AND YT.direction = t.direction AND YT.test = t.test 
SET is_deleted = 1
WHERE YT.results = 'Pass'
```

Comment: Thank you it worked! How about if I want to hide them instead of deleting them?

Comment: You can introduce a new field in that table named `is_deleted`. And later update the status of `is_deleted` field to 1 for those similar entries having `Pass` result.

Comment: I've updated the answer. Please check the update under the **EDIT** section of my answer.

Comment: Thank you I managed to display the table I wanted. Using inner join didn't really cross my mind.

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE passed
    FROM `table` AS passed
INNER JOIN `table` AS failed ON failed.id = passed.id
AND failed.class = passed.class
AND failed.direction = passed.direction
AND failed.test = passed.test
AND failed.results = 'Fail'
WHERE
    passed.results = 'Pass'
```

But you should first check, if those really are the results you want to delete. So use a select first.

```
SELECT passed.* 
FROM
    `table` AS passed
INNER JOIN `table` AS failed ON failed.id = passed.id
AND failed.class = passed.class
AND failed.direction = passed.direction
AND failed.test = passed.test
AND failed.results = 'Fail'
WHERE
    passed.results = 'Pass'
```

Also backup your data before playing with it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want distinct results for each row, you can create an unique index with the rows `id` `class`, `direction`, `test`, `results` included, and you can prevent inserting those rows to the table at the first place.

```
ALTER TABLE `table` 
ADD CONSTRAINT uc_RowUniqueness 
UNIQUE (id,class,direction,test,results)
```

But if your need failed results to be inserted without caring for duplicate records, that's not a solution. Maybe you can use a trigger then.

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE TRIGGER delete_similar
BEFORE INSERT ON table
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN    
    IF NEW.results == 'Pass' THEN
       DELETE FROM table 
           WHERE id=NEW.id AND class=NEW.class 
           AND direction=NEW.direction AND results='Pass'
    END IF;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```